# how to display image through XML to html

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Hie i am practicing XML , Javascript. I want to display image for each animal in a row. But my main problem arises uneven nesting in images . Some have two images while some have 4.  I have XML File as follows:

```
<zoo>
     <animal>
        <common_name>Elephant</common_name>
        <images>
            <image>elephant13.jpg</image>
        </images>
    </animal>
    <animal>
        <common_name>Emu</common_name>
        <images>
            <image>emu12.jpg</image>
            <image>emu26.jpg</image>
            <image>emu23.jpg</image>
        </images>
    </animal>
    <animal>
        <common_name>Lion</common_name>
        <images>
            <image>lion51.jpg</image>
            <image>lion46.jpg</image>
        </images>
    </animal>
<zoo>`
```

My javascript for img is :

```
for(var y = 0; y < noOfImages ; y++)
{
   if (images)
   {
      images.src ="images/" + zooRoot.getElementsByTagName("image")[i].firstChild.nodeValue; 
      ul.appendChild(images);
   }   
}
```

Comment: Kindly create a fiddle for us to make code changes.

Comment: i cannot add xml file

Comment: ok. let me see. Wait

Comment: are you using Jquery by any chance?

Comment: Looks like your XML is malformed. Have a look at last line, it should be a close tag

Comment: Low quality text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This get's the document node of xml and queries for images from it. Once you have the array, you iterate over it and get the inner text from the node.
    var xmlimages = xml.getElementsByTagName('image');

```
for(var i=0; i< xmlimages.length; i++) {
    images.src = "images/" + xmlimages[i].innerHTML.trim(); // trim used to remove all the white space from text that you get when you use innerHTML
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get Animal as an object, then create a HTMLstring and insert it in node;

```
var animalsNode = zooRoot.getElementsByTagName('animal');
var animals = [];
for(var i=0; i<animalsNode.length; i++){
  var animalName = animalsNode[i].getElementsByTagName("common_name").innerHTML;
  var animalImageNodes = animalsNode[i].getElementsByTagName("image");
  var animalImages = [];

  //will store image paths into animalImages
  for(var j=0; j<animalImageNodes.length; j++){
    animalImages.push("image/" + animalImageNodes.innerHTML);
  }
  animals.push({
    common_name: animalName,
    images: animalImages //array of image urls
  })
}
var animalsHTML = function(animals){
  //lets cereate string with "html table"
  var animalsHtml = "<table>";
  for(var i=0; i<animals.length; i++){
    animalsHtml += "<tr>";

    animalsHtml += "<td>" + animals[i].name + "</td>"
                 + "<td><img src='" + animals[i].images[0] + "' /></td>";

    animalsHtml += "</tr>";
  }
  animalsHtml += "</table>";

  return animalsHtml;
}

tableNode.innerHTML = animalsHTML(animals);
```

or you can define animal array more functional way =)

```
var animals = zooRoot.getElementsByTagName('animal').map(function(animalNode){
  return {
    common_name: animalNode.getElementsByTagName('common_name')[0].innerHTML,
    images: animalNode.getElementsByTagName('image').map(function(imageNode){
      return "image/" + imageNode.innerHTML;
    })
  };
});
//and more js style of draw-function
var animalsHTML = function(animals){
  return "<table>" + animals.reduce(function(curr, next){
    return curr + "<tr><td>" + next.name + "</td>"
                  + "<td>" 
                  + next.images.reduce(function(c, n){
                      return c + "<img src='" + n "' />"
                    },'')
                  + "</td>"
                + "</tr>";
  }, '') + "</table>";
}
tableNode.innerHTML = animalsHTML(animals);
```

I didn't test it, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please insert loop on node:

```
for(var y = 0; y < noOfImages ; y++)
{
   if (images)
   {
      var imgData = zooRoot.getElementsByTagName("image");
      for (i = 0; i <imgData.length; i++) {
            images.src ="images/" + imgData[i].firstChild.nodeValue; 
            ul.appendChild(images);
      }
   }   
}
```